# When does the set of possible walk lengths start being $\varepsilon$-dense?

Tags: graph-theory, fourier-analysis, irrational-numbers

Let $\Gamma$ be a finite directed graph, and suppose each directed edge $e \colon a \to b$ has a positive real length.  Suppose given vertices $x, y \in \Gamma$, and suppose there are infinitely many directed walks from $x$ to $y$.  For any $\varepsilon > 0$, I am interested in finding $N \in \mathbb{R}$ so that for every $L > N$, there exists a walk from $x$ to $y$ whose length is within $\varepsilon$ of $L$.

Of course, such an $N$ may not exist.  For example, if every edge length is an integer, then we can never accommodate $\varepsilon < 1/2$.  However, $x$ admits two self-walks with lengths that are linearly independent over $\mathbb{Q}$, then it seems that $N = N(\Gamma, \varepsilon)$ always exists.

How can I find a bound on $N$ as a function of $\Gamma$ and $\varepsilon$?